# Wrong UITableView position after pull to refresh

Tags: xcode, uitableview

in my app this is the tableview position:

[image]

> When i run pull to refresh, the position is:

[image]

Why does the tableview stay down?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how do you use the UIRefreshControl in your code ?

Looks like you probably miss a `refreshControl.endRefreshing()`

Comment: in viewdidLoad `refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];`
   `[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`
    `[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];`

Comment: and refresh method: `refresh {
    [feeds removeAllObjects];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    NSLog(@"fetching data from the server");
}`